# Parse string values into integer in a nested array

Tags: ruby

I have a nested array with string values:

```
a = [["2000", "2004"], ["2005", "2007"]]
```

I am converting the value to integer like this:

```
int_val = []

a.each do |a|
  int_val << a.map(&:to_i)
end

int_val #=> [[2000, 2004], [2005, 2007]]
```

Is there any short solution or one line code for this? `[["2000", "2004"], ["2005", "2007"]].map(&:to_i)` will not work.

Comment: `[["2000", "2004"], ["2005", "2007"]].map{|row| row.map(&:to_i)}` works...

Comment: @dawg, you may have missed that halfelf gave that as a solution earlier.

Comment: `a.each do |a|` – re-using an outer variable name ([variable shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)) can lead to confusion. Don't do that.

Answer (score 8):

How about "two dimensional" `map`?

```
a = [["2000", "2004"], ["2005", "2007"]]
a.map {|i| i.map(&:to_i) }  # => [[2000, 2004], [2005, 2007]]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Enumerable#each_with_object`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object):

```
a = [["2000", "2004"], ["2005", "2007"]]
a.each_with_object([]) do |a, int_val|
  int_val << a.map(&:to_i)
end
#⇒ [[2000, 2004], [2005, 2007]]
```

<s>It should be less memory-consuming than `map.map`.</s> (credits @pascalbetz for pointing out that’s not true.)

Comment: why would that use less memory? can you expand on that @mudasobwa?

Comment: @pascalbetz After a careful re-think, I am to admit I was wrong. Updated the answer.

Comment: thanks for updating.
Actually I was not "pointing out", just wondering why it could use less memory. Still wondering.... might write a benchmark at some point.

Comment: @pascalbetz it's even slightly _less_ efficient because – unlike `map` – the array has to be resized as new elements are being added.

Answer (score 4):

A single `map`.

```
a.map { |i, j| [i.to_i, j.to_i] }
```

Of course this is not a general solution, but is good for your example.

Answer (score 1):

Out of curiosity:

```
a = [["2000", "2004"], ["2005", "2007"]]
a.flatten.map(&:to_i).each_slice(2).to_a
#⇒ [[2000, 2004], [2005, 2007]]
```

Comment: It's curious that this was awarded the greenie considering that it only works when `a.size == a[0].size == a[1].size == 2`.

Comment: Indeed, I was also surprised.